# How to calculate projectile range C# Unity 3D (2D project)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, projectile

I found a formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_projectile) where it is described how to calculate Range of a Projectile based on physics, but I still can't find a way to make it work. Formula that i want to use is d=(v^2*sin2φ)/g . If anyone can calculate in another way it's okay. Just give a solution. Following code is not calculating correct position, and is not instantiating trampoline at next position where player (projectile in this case) will touch ground. Let's suppose player will land at (10,0), code is instantiating trampoline at (100,0).

P.S. My project is 2D and it's being developed with C#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NextDropLocation : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject trampoline, player;
float speed;

float CalculateAngle()
{
    var dir = player.transform.position;
    var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    return angle;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    speed = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude;
}

float InstantiateNext(float speed, float angle)
{
    return (Mathf.Pow(speed, 2) * 2 * Mathf.Sin(angle) * Mathf.Cos(angle) / 9.81f); //formula from Wikipedia
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    var angle = CalculateAngle();
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Trampoline")
    {
        player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(5, 5), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        Instantiate(trampoline, new Vector3(InstantiateNext(speed, angle), -3.65f), player.transform.rotation);

    }
    else
        print("You landed on the ground. Game Over!");
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

}
```

}

Comment: d=(v^2*sin2φ)/g translates to d= (Math.Pow(speed,2)*Math.Sin(2*angle))/9.81f Or am I missing something? Where did u get the "* Mathf.Cos(angle)" and the " *2 "?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not giving the right range becouse you this formula calculates the range with Earths gravity but you are using custom gravity and your object has custom weight so you have to tweak the formula just a little bit.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to change formula. You have the wikipedia link at the top of post.

Comment: If the example you gave is right, than just setting the 'g' to 0.981 will give you the right answer of the equation.